# Angular mat-date-picker format inside calendar

Tags: angular, angular-material, datepicker, mat-datepicker

I'm using Angular Material datepicker and I have a problem with the format inside the calendar and can't find the place where to configure it.

I have this format right now:

[image]

where can I change this to a format like YYYY-MM-DD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The button (circled) is **Month Year label**.

Would recommend using `MomentDateModule` for customizing the date format easily.

**Step 1**: Install @angular/material-moment-adapter.

```
npm install @angular/material-moment-adapter
```

**Step 2**: Import `MatMomentDateModule` into `AppModule`

```js
import { MatMomentDateModule } from '@angular/material-moment-adapter';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...,
    MatMomentDateModule,
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**Step 3**: Provide customized `MY_FORMATS` into `providers` section for `AppModule` or `Component`. (Below code is for `Component`)

**Step 3.1**: Provide the desired format for `monthYearLabel` and `monthYearA11yLabel`.

```js
import { MAT_DATE_FORMATS } from '@angular/material/core';

export const MY_FORMATS = {
  parse: {
    dateInput: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
  },
  display: {
    dateInput: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
    monthYearLabel: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
    dateA11yLabel: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
    monthYearA11yLabel: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
  },
};

@Component({
  ...
  providers: [{ provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: MY_FORMATS }]
})
```

[Sample Solution on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-3mky76)

---

### References

[MomentDateModule formats](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview#momentdatemodule-formats)

Comment: I had another custom date format for my input fields and that messed it up for the calendar with your answer, but made some changes and it works now so thank you!